# Inheriting Exceptions in C++11?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class called `Matrix<t>`, My professor asked me to write an exception class:

```
Matrix::IllegalInitialization
```

Such that it includes the function `what()`, So I wrote (In Matrix.h):

```
template<class T>
class Matrix<T>::IllegalInitialization {
public:
    std::string what() const {
        return "Mtm matrix error: Illegal initialization values";
    }
};
```

But I have a problem that this class doesn't inherit Exceptions, how to fix this?

I want the following to work:

```
     try {
         Dimensions dim(0,5);
         Matrix<int> mat(dim);
} catch (const mtm::Matrix<int>::IllegalInitialization & e){ cout<< e.what() <<endl;
}
```

---

**Edit:**
Is this how should my code look like?

```
template<class T>
class Matrix<T>::IllegalInitialization : public std::exception {
public:
   const char* what() const override {
      return "Mtm matrix error: Illegal initialization values";
   }
};
```

I am getting:

error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version

Comment: Just inherit from `std::exception`? I don't understand the problem

Comment: Declare `IllegalInitialization` as a nested class of your `Matric` class template.

Comment: inheritance is actually not that common in the standard library, but `std::exception` is made to be inherited from, you fix it by inheriting from it

Comment: the question is double unclear. First, why cant you just inherit from `std::exception`? And second, "I want the following to work" should already work (also without inheriting from `std::exception`). Please clarify what is your problem

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the compiler error if there is one, or explain actual and expected outcome

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry for the confusion I made, to summarise, how may I inherit std::exception?

Comment: do you know how to inherit `foo` from `bar`?

Comment: yes but then  I would have class Matrix<T>::IllegalInitialization::public std::exception

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am inheriting 3 classes

Comment: there is no inheritance in the code you posted, but anyhow you can inherit from as many classes as you like. What is the problem?

Comment: then I should write: Matrix<T>::IllegalInitialization::public std::exception?

Comment: @Daniel post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Daniel thats wrong syntax, but inheriting from `std::exception` is not different than inheriting from any other type. If you have problem with code you should include the code ([mcve]) and the error message

Comment: @idclev463035818 updated my question and added what I did, please take a look

Comment: Note that your current code *will work* as it is, because you can throw literally anything in C++. Inheriting from `std::exception` is a good practice, but your class already quacks like a duck, which is enough for some uses.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen how it should be for perfect use? plus how to fix the error

Comment: What does template<class T>
class Matrix<T>::IllegalInitialization  even means?

Comment: Have you tried typing your error message into a search engine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829852/exception-specification-of-overriding-function-is-more-lax-than-base-version

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. We dont need to see the `Matrix<T>` and the code you posted is incomplete. Trying to compile it will result in errors unrelated to your question

Answer (score 2):

The `what()` method of `std::exception` is (cf [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what)):

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
```

Your method is not declared `noexcept` hence it cannot override `std::exception::what()`.

Comment: I have added noexcept and all works fine, just to summarise is my code well written now?

Comment: @Daniel you need to understand that I cannot tell you if code is correct when I can only see fragments of it. As already mentioned, the code you did post is incomplete and when I would try to compile it I get errors unrelated to your question. In any case, eventually it is always you who has to understand every detail and make sure that the code is correct

Comment: @Daniel inheriting from `std::runtime_error` is more convenient, because it already has an implementation of `what` and a constructor that takes the string to be printed

Comment: But should const appear at the end or as I wrote it (The const which means *this won't be affected)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with a little bigger amount of code lines, but it more flexible

Usage example:

```
try {
    throw MatrixErrors{ErrorCode::kIllegalInitialization};
} catch (const MatrixErrors& error) {
    std::cerr << error.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

The code:

```
enum class ErrorCode {
  kIllegalInitialization,
};

// Helper function to get an explanatory string for error
inline std::string GetErrorString(ErrorCode error_code) {
  switch (error_code) {
    case ErrorCode::kIllegalInitialization:
      return "Mtm matrix error: Illegal initialization values";
  }
  return {};
}

class MatrixErrors : public std::runtime_error {
 public:
  explicit MatrixErrors(ErrorCode error_code) : std::runtime_error{GetErrorString(error_code)}, code_{error_code} {}

  ErrorCode GetCode() const noexcept { return code_; }

 private:
  ErrorCode code_;
};
```